# Is this poison sumac?

Tags: weeds, safety, poison-ivy

Was just pulling this stuff out of the ground all over my back yard, and then got suspicious about the red leaves.[image]

Comment: definitely could be poison sumac.  Get gloves and pull that sucker out.  You've got a wonderful bed of Japanese Pachysandra!  Pull all plants that aren't Pachysandra terminalis.  They don't belong.  Do you live where poisonous sumac is common?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That absolutely is not sumac or poison ivy. It's got a dogwood looking leaf on it. Look above this plant and see what type tree is growing over it. It's possibly some type tree seedling.

Comment: Poplars, oaks, cherry and pine.

Comment: Not a tree but a shrub. See the long horizontal stolon/sucker on the right. The gold part seems similar to Wusteria (also with gold stolons), but the green part is not like it.

Comment: Wisteria maybe, a strange type of ash? but not any kind of sumac I've ever seen before and definitely not a poplar, oak, cherry, or pine! or a dogwood (Cornus) yeah I going with Wisteria because the leafy bit next to it has a very long running stem(bottom right) and i'm always cutting them off this time of year! hope it helps

Comment: So we have a consensus: *not* the culprit?

Comment: You could just pop in to the local garden centre and take a leaf with you- compare that to the wisteria they have in stock- should be a match. We had loads of customers do that years ago- (thinking a self seeded chicken's foot hellebore was cannabis?- used to drive me bonkers!)